# Decode script return different value from my relative timelock

Tags: smartcontracts, hash-time-locked-contract

I want to lock a UTXO for 90 days.

My Binary is:

```
00000000010000000011101101010011
```

And my sequence is: `533B40`

When I decode the witness script with `bitcoin-cli decodescript` I can see `4209491`.
Where `4209491` comes from?

**UPDATE**

It's seems that the `533B40` convert into little endian and the convert into base 10

```
printf 533B40 | tac -rs .. 
403B53
```

Then convert in base 2

```
echo "ibase=16; obase=2; 403B53" | bc
10000000011101101010011
```

And then in base10

```
echo "ibase=2;10000000011101101010011" | bc
4209491
```

why decodescript has this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decodescript` has this behavior because integers in Bitcoin are little endian. So `decodescript` is telling you what number the script interpreter would use when it processes your script.